# Positioning multiple fixed sticky elements with Waypoints

Tags: jquery-waypoints

I'm using [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) and their [Sticky](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/) shortcut to 'stick' an element with the id `stick-this` to the top of the viewport once it gets scrolled past.  I am having some difficulty positioning the element *past* another fixed element on the screen, however.

There is a `<div>` with a class `.header` which always remains fixed.  I am trying to position the `top` of the new element to the `height()` of the `.header` element so they are 'stacked' on top of one another and both visible.  This is the code I am using to accomplish this:

```
var sticky = new Waypoint.Sticky({
    element: $('#stick-this')[0],
    handler: function() {
        $(".stuck").css({ "top" : $(".header").height() });
    }
})
```

So, essentially, once the `#stick-this` is scrolled past, it becomes sticky with a `position:fixed` class and the `top` is dynamically determined by the `height()` of `.header`.

This works great until I scroll back up, and the `top` style is still applied to this element, in spite of the `stuck` class not being applied anymore.

So when I scroll past, the element ends up like this

```
<div id="stick-this" class="stuck" style="top:70px /*or whatever the height() ends up being */">
```

and when I scroll back up the element ends up like this with the top property still in place

```
<div id="stick-this" class="" style="top:70px /*I need this back to 0px */">
```

Is it possible to have a function called when the "sticky" is removed, so that the inline style property can be set to `top:0px` or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else struggling with this, I ended up dynamically writing the CSS when the sticky element's class is initiated and inserting it into the head:

```
var sticky = new Waypoint.Sticky({
        element: $('#stick-this')[0],
        offset: $('.header').outerHeight(true),
        handler: function(direction) {
            $("<style>")
            .prop("type", "text/css")
            .html("\
            .stuck {\
                position: fixed;\
                top:" + $(".header").height() + "px;\
            }")
            .appendTo("head");
        }
    })
```

so, the class will be added with the correct `top` positioning, and once the class is removed, the `top` property is inherently returned back to `0px`.

It's important to have the `\` after each line break in the `.html()` portion of this code in order for it to work.